# How much work is involved to change a conventional boiler to a combi boiler?

Tags: heating, central-heating, uk

We live in a circa 8 year old detached house in the UK.

We've been having some problems with our heating system, mainly the hot water tank and we're wondering how much work is involved to change to a combi boiler (we want to get rid of the hot water tank so we can use the cupboard as stairs to our attic anyway so this is the perfect excuse ;-)).

Looking online there are some conflicting accounts of the work involved.

Is it just changing our boiler in the kitchen to a combi boiler, removing the hot water tank upstairs and "joining up some pipes" or will we need work done in every room?

Trying to understand the amount of required "damage" that might happen!

Answer (score 2):

> **will we need work done in every room?**

I haven't done this but I'm pretty sure that most rooms do not need to be touched. Only

- The boiler location obviously
- The airing-cupboard - removal of hot-water tank, replumbing.
- The loft (attic) - removal of header tank for hot-water etc.

You are changing from this

[image]

to this

[image]

<sup>*Images from [wellwarm plumbing](http://www.wellwarmplumbing.co.uk/two-pipe-boiler.htm) - no affiliation*</sup>

The diagrams above are the best I could find but have a couple of anomalies:

- the pump and zone-valves are usually next to the boiler, not next to the hot-water tank.
- I would expect to connect to existing hot tap pipes in airing cupboard, not run new supply pipes to a different location.

Details obviously depend on the exact arrangements in your home - but in general, I can see no reason to alter anything in other rooms.